# Default Grub2 entry doesn't point lastest kernel version + "selinuxfs mount failed" boot error: how to repair?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, kernel

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 in multi-boot with linux (Mandriva 2011/Grub Legacy). First it seemed to work. But on my first update in Ubuntu, I was "strongly adviced" by the system to update grub and got a grub menu with 3 sub-menus and 887 entries !!

So I cutomized Grub2 and updated it (grub-update). I left Grub2 generate automatic entries for my Ubuntu and put my Mandriva entries in /etc/grub.d/40_custom.

- The problem is my default entry in grub menu ("ubuntu") + 2 others ("linux","linux recovery") always point to the *FIRST* kernel version of Ubuntu, not the *LATEST*.

I have 4 new versions of kernel and when selected I can boot with them fine. Even more, when I select a specific kernel version in the grub menu, I don't get the "selinuxfs mount failed error" ...

I set the symbolic links in my /boot (vmlinuz, vmlinuz-dektop, ...) to point to latest kernel version before reboot. But when I check after reboot they *always point to the fist version of kernel* !! And these menu entries are generated automatically by Grub2 with grub-update.

- Futhermore there must be something wrong with the automatically generated entries ("ubuntu","linux","linux recovery") to cause the "mount failed selinuxfs on .../selinux no such file or directory" error, even if it doesn't stop the boot process.

So what can I do ?

Here are extracts of /boot/grub.cfg :

- 1. default menu entry "Ubuntu"

     ```
     menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-35aa379d-1870-4ef0-add3-ee1f2324257f' {  
     recordfail  
     load_video  
     gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode  
     insmod gzio  
     insmod part_msdos  
      insmod ext2  
     set root='hd0,msdos1'  
         if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then  
           search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  86e4c77e-6549-478c-9a75-166a21019644  
         else  
           search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 86e4c77e-6549-478c-9a75-166a21019644  
         fi  
     linux   /vmlinuz-desktop root=/dev/sda10 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff  
     }
     ```
- 2. specific kernel version menu entry

     ```
     menuentry 'Ubuntu, avec Linux 3.13.0-43-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-43-generic-advanced-35aa379
     d-1870-4ef0-add3-ee1f2324257f' {  
     recordfail  
     load_video  
     gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode  
     insmod gzio  
     insmod part_msdos  
     insmod ext2  
     set root='hd0,msdos1'  
     if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then  
     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  86e4c77e-6549-478c-9a75-166a21019644  
     else  
     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 86e4c77e-6549-478c-9a75-166a21019644  
     fi  
     echo    'Chargement de Linux 3.13.0-43-generic…'  
     linux   /vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic root=UUID=35aa379d-1870-4ef0-add3-ee1f2324257f ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff  
     echo    'Chargement du disque mémoire initial…'  
     initrd  /initrd.img-3.13.0-43-generic  
         }
     ```

Comment: have you tried to invoke `grub-mkconfig` ? see `info grub`. try `ls /` to see your _vmlinuz_ and _intird_ images.

Comment: Not yet. Will look into it as soon as I have solved some failing hardware issue that has just happened !

Comment: what kind of hw-issue ? could it stick together?

Comment: maybe the update went a bit wrong? have you tried to update your kernel again?

Comment: I don't think my hardware pb is related : my graphic card seems to have died and I had it sent back. To be replaced, or so I hope ! As for wether the "update went wrong", I'm not sure what you mean. The "grub update" went wrong indeed but I don't know why ! Updating the kernel ? I have several kernels in the boot as I said ; grub choose which to use by default. THe problem is it chooses the wrong one i.e. not the last one.